# PHP/MySQL copy data in chunks from one table to another via a load more button

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure their is probably a better way... Is it possible to copy items form `table1(column)` to `table2(column)` in data row chunks of 25 with a load more button?

How would I do this? Where would I find information on this? Thank you.

Comment: You can always SELECT some data and INSERT it into another table, not a good solution but you can. Can you please provide a little more detail as to what you are trying to do and give some sample code, whatever you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you. You can implement it in php to load more action.

every time after clicking more button change offset and limit in mysql query

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 0, 25;

load more...

INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 25, 25;

load more...

INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 50, 25;
```

....

....

Commplete code.

1.Just copy and paste following code in page1.php

```
<div id='message'></div>

<a href='#' id='LoadMore' >Load More</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var page = 1;
    $("#LoadMore").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"page2.php",
            data:{page:page},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#message").append(response); 
                page++;
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

2.Copy following code in page2.php

and change mysql_server, mysql_user, mysql_password, database_name argument in first two line

```
<?php
//set argument as your mysql server
$connect = mysql_connect("mysql_server","mysql_user","mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database_name",$connect);

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
$limit = 25;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 limit $offset, $limit";
mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_affected_rows();
echo "$rows rows added to table2 from table1<br>";
?>
```

3.Run page1.php in browser... and load data to table2

**Now showing data from table2 without refreshing page as required (user2714387 said in comment)**

4.Copy and paste following code in page3.php

```
<table width="300" border="1" id='data_grid'></table>

<a href='javascript://' id='LoadMore' >Load More</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var page = 1;
    $("#LoadMore").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"page4.php",
            data:{page:page},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#data_grid").append(response); 
                page++;
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

4.Copy following code in page4.php

```
<?php
    //set argument as your mysql server
    $connect = mysql_connect("mysql_server","mysql_user","mysql_password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name",$connect);

    $page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
    $limit = 25;
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 limit $offset, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numRows>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //get field data and set to the following row
            echo "<tr><td>field 1</td><td>field 2</td><td>field 3</td></tr>";
                    //edit row as you table data

        }
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='3'> No more data </td></tr>";
    }
    exit;
?>
```

6.Run page4.php in browser

Comment: And don't use `mysql_*` functions, because they are deprecated. Use PDO or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @salim When the new table is updated how would I updated a list that shows the entire table without reloading the page?

Comment: @user2714387: answer is editted as your requirments (When the new table is updated how would I updated a list that shows the entire table without reloading the page)

Comment: @salim: Can you suggest compatible code that would list table2's elements in a functional drag and drop ranking system? Tried Jquery but the ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js line kills the functionality of that drag and drop.

Comment: @user2714387: Please create a new question giving table structure and requirements as much as clear because it is not fare to edit more this answer it will violate answer of this question.

Comment: @salim As requested here is the [link to the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620425/how-do-i-fix-an-ajax-conflict-with-jquery-drag-n-drop-ranking) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620425/how-do-i-fix-an-ajax-conflict-with-jquery-drag-n-drop-ranking