# How do I fix an Ajax conflict with jQuery Drag n Drop ranking?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two sets of code [Loadmore Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565801/php-mysql-copy-data-in-chunks-from-one-table-to-another-via-a-load-more-button) And Jqueury [Drag N Drop](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/) but they do not work as one.

How can I merge them together to function as one code?

Here is the Problem:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript">
```

This Line is needed by the Loadmore Button and kills the UI function of the Drag and Drop elements.

Drag N Drop:

```
<title>jQuery Dynamic Drag'n Drop</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js">

</script><script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

$(function() {
    $("#contentLeft ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
        $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
            $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
        });                                                              
    }                                 
    });
});

}); 
</script>
```

DND updateDB.php

```
<?php 
require("db.php");

    $action                 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']); 
    $updateRecordsArray     = $_POST['recordsArray'];

if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

$listingCounter = 1;
foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {

    $query = "UPDATE records SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE recordID = " . $recordIDValue;
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
    $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($updateRecordsArray);
echo '</pre>';
echo 'If you refresh the page, you will see that records will stay just as you modified.';
}?>
```

DND main PHP:

```
    <ul>
    <?php
            $query  = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY recordListingID ASC";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            ?>
                <li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $row['recordID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['recordID'] . ". " . $row['recordText']; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

---

Loadmore:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var page = 1;
$("#LoadMore").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"page4.php",
        data:{page:page},
        success: function(response) {
            $("#data_grid").append(response); 
            page++;
        }
    });
}); 
});</script>
```

Loadmore page4.php

```
<?php
//set argument as your mysql server
$connect = mysql_connect("mysql_server","mysql_user","mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database_name",$connect);

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;
$limit = 25;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 limit $offset, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numRows>0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //get field data and set to the following row
        echo "<tr><td>field 1</td><td>field 2</td><td>field 3</td></tr>";
                //edit row as you table data

    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='3'> No more data </td></tr>";
}
exit;
?>
```

What am I missing? Can I fix this? Am I going to have to scrap the Jquery Drag N Drop? Is there an alternative that I should be using?

Background: A user will rate listed items in the order they deem fit. The total possible Items exceed 300,000 but the user will probably only utilize the first few hundred and the rest is used as a searchable database to add an odd item into the list. I can get the 2 codes in question to work separately but when I attempt the combination they create conflict.

Thank you for your time in assisting this project.

Comment: One is too old, the other doesn't support the older library. Either update one of them tot he latest version, or downgrade the other to a really old version that probably doesn't exist. Or you can be lazy and include jQuery twice and use $.noConflict.

Comment: There's no reason you can't upgrade the first snippet to the newer version of jQuery UI. also, never include /1/, always specify a specific version, both for caching reasons and for code reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

are same (jQuery file)

So use only one

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Check and let me know

Comment: Removing the original Jquery file does not fix the UI of the drag and drop.

Comment: Removing the `jquery.min.js` and keeping the `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` was the key.